# draw(_ rect:CGRect) is not updating Playground Assistant editor preview

Tags: draw, preview, swift-playground, drawinrect

I tried different code in draw implementation. From custom UIBezierPath to simply changing background colour to random. Results are successfully updated in preview, which is shown under the line on clicking "Show Results" button. But nothing happens to assistant editor timeline view.

Here is my draw override

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), green: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), blue: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max), alpha: 1)
    super.draw(rect)
}
```

UPD: liveView is assigned properly. It shows but is shows only first result of draw.

Comment: Did you properly assign your view to the playground's live view? Like this: `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = yourView`

Comment: Eric Aya Yes it is ok. Live view is shown. Problem is that nothing updates in it

Comment: Ok maybe you need the playground to run indefinitely instead of step by step, maybe the live view needs it, try this: `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true`

Comment: needsIndefiniteExecution is set too(